# What is the redis equivalent of storing an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'd like to use Redis and not my session for this for obvious reasons.

Old country code :

```
session[:some_stuff] = @my_objects.map(&:id)
```

Then later :

```
session[:some_stuff].each{|obj| ..
```

Alternatively,

I would like to store this map of id's into redis. And then retrieve them. I can't find any thing relevant on other web resources. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to use the `redis-store` gem thinking that would solve a few problems but it turns out it doesn't work. Even the supposibly stable 1.0.0 version.

So this is what I did and it worked out extraordinarily well :

```
def first_method
  $redis = Redis.new
  @customers.map(&:id).each{|c|$redis.sadd('export', c)}


def other_method
  @customers = [] 
  $redis.smembers('export').each{|c|@customers << Customer.find(c)}
```

**Notes**:

You only need to identify what $redis is once in one method. Then it saves itself into a stateless place outside of your MVC architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't written about how you have your Redis connection/adapter set up but it's basically `SADD` for adding elements to a Redis set and `SMEMBERS` to retrieve all the elements.

http://redis.io/commands#set

Comment: Yah I read that, but none of their documentation works for a layman. For example, any command in the doc will fail because `myset` is undefined.

Comment: You need a redis adapter. https://github.com/redis/redis-rb Also, myset is just the name of a sample key for the documentation. You need to define your own key which is basically just a string.